# Error while Compiling "|75|error: cannot convert 'std::vector<int>' to 'int'" while implementing bfs

Tags: c++, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I am implementing bfs (Breadth First Search ) for the graph , but I am getting an error while I pass  the starting value of the vector to an integer, for the dfs function to perform, as in the dfs function I have passed the source of the vector, i.e the first element of the vector.
**error is on the line where start is declared to v[i]** 
Here is the complete code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
vector<int> v[10];
bool visited[10];
int level[10];
int a = 0;
int arr[10];

void dfs(int s) //function should run only one time

{
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(s);
    visited[s] = true;
    level[s] = 0;
    while (!q.empty())

    {
        int p = q.front();
        arr[a] = p;
        a++;

        q.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < v[p].size(); i++)

        {
            if (visited[v[p][i]] == false) {
                level[v[p][i]] = level[p] + 1;
                q.push(v[p][i]);
                visited[v[p][i]] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char c;
    int start; // starting element of the vector
    int i = 0; // for keeping track of the parent
    int countt = 0; // keep track of the no of parents
    bool check;
    printf("Child or Parent ?");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    while (countt <= 10) {
        if (c == 'c') {
            check = true;
            int j = 0;
            while (check) {
                // to keep the track of the child;
                scanf("%d", &v[i][j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        if (c == 'p')

        {

            scanf("%d", &v[i]);
            if (i == 0)

            {
                start = v[i];
            }
            i++;
            countt++;
        }
    }
    printf(" Vector input completed");
    dfs(start);
    printf("DFS completed, printing the dfs now  ");
    for (int g = 0; g <= 10; g++)

    {
        printf("%d", &arr[g]);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all C and C++ are different languages. Your code is C++, it is not C, there is no `std::queue`, `std::vector`, etc in C.

Comment: Not much can be added to the compiler message, other than the `scanf` a few lines above the error is also wrong, but the compiler may not be able to tell you because `scanf` is able to take anything as a parameter. One of the reasons you shouldn't use it.

Comment: The `printf` a few lines down is also incorrect. Again, don't use it. use `cin` and `cout` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, `v` is an array of size 10 containing `vector`'s. However, `start` is an `int`, so there is nothing strange in getting an error when trying to assign one to another.

I believe that you wanted `v` to be either an array of `int`s or `vector` of `int`s. In such a case you just have to declare `v` properly: `int v[10]` or `vector<int> v(10)`.

This is general syntax: if you want to declare a vector with known size then you have to put it in `()`, not in `[]`. Note that you can also fill the vector with some initial values (say zeroes) by writing `vector<int> v(10, 0)`.

In case got you wrong and you wanted to store a graph as `vector` of `vector`s, then you can write `vector<vector<int>> v(10)`.